# Wrong 3rd argument but was supposed to work via video tutorial

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was following a [tutorial](https://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Retrieving-data-from-main-activity-CursorLoader/377485/406768-4.html?autoplay=true) but when I reached the part to make:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

the `this` was creating problems. It was referencing `MainActivity` but it won't accept the implementation.

Its specific message was:

> Wrong 3rd argument type. Found:
>   'com.example.plainolnotes.MainActivity', required:
>   'android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

```
package com.example.plainolnotes;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    // @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) //Not a good long term solution

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        insertNote("New_note");
        /*
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                DBOpenHelper.ALL_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null);
                */
        String[] from = {DBOpenHelper.NOTE_TEXT};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        //getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        /*
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        */
    }

    private void insertNote(String noteText) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.NOTE_TEXT, noteText);
        Uri noteUri = getContentResolver().insert(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                values);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Inserted note " + noteUri.getLastPathSegment());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        //Loaded when data is needed for the contentProvider
        return new CursorLoader(this, NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        //data needs to be wiped out
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: I cleaned it and it remained the same.

Comment: Wait, I tried an alt. method called "getSupportLoaderManager()" and it worked! Do you have any knowledge of this and how it differs?

Answer (score 4):

problem is with import statement

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
```

whereas required is

```
android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
```

replace it to solve your problem

Comment: I switched it and now the problem is underlining "LoaderManager" of 'implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>'

If I alt+enter, it gave me two options which either option made it worse.

Comment: Wait man. You got me thinking and through some searching, I found 'getSupportLoaderManager()' to be the solution! Do you have any knowledge about this function?

Answer (score 1):

How I solved mine:

```
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;    
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;    
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;    
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;    

//Note getSupportLoaderManager()    
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

ummm, what i actuallt did, i switch to using  **getSupportLoaderManager()**  instead of **getLoaderManager()**.
so you can do like this

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```